# Improve LINQ query performance?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

```
public List<Agents_main_view_distinct> getActiveAgents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
       myactiveagents = null;            
       myactiveagents = mydb.Agents_main_view_distincts.Where(u => u.Status.Equals("Existing") && u.DateJoined2 >=start && u.DateJoined2 <=end).OrderByDescending(ac => ac.Recno).ToList();            
       return myactiveagents;
     }
```

I have a simple LINQ query that queries a view.My worry is its performance. It works well with few hundreds records but when the records are over 2000. The SQL server times out.
Things I have done to improve on the performance.
1. Wrote a query to query the tables directly (No improvement).
2. Reduced unnecessary columns, previous it had 27 columns, reduces it to 20.

In a desperation attempt I increased the server time out to 600. But still it was timing out.

View SQL query

```
SELECT dbo.Agents.Recno, dbo.Agents.Rec_date, dbo.Agents.AgentsId, dbo.Agents.AgentsName, dbo.Agents.Industry_status, dbo.Agents.DOB, dbo.Agents.Branch, 
                  dbo.Agents.MobileNumber, dbo.Agents.MaritalStatus, dbo.Agents.PIN, dbo.Agents.Gender, dbo.Agents.Email, dbo.Agents.ProvisionalLicense, 
                  dbo.Agents.IRALicenseNumber, dbo.Agents.PreviousCompany, dbo.Agents.YearsOfExperience, dbo.Agents.COPNumber, dbo.Agents.DateJoined AS DateJoined2, 
                  dbo.Agents.DateJoined, dbo.Agents.PreviousOccupation, dbo.Agents.ProffesionalQualification, dbo.Agents.EducationalQualification, dbo.Agents.Status, 
                  dbo.Agents.Termination_Date2 AS Termination_Date, dbo.Agents.Comments, dbo.Agents.Temination_code, dbo.Agents.Company_ID, dbo.Agents.Submit_By, 
                  dbo.Agents.PassportPhoto, dbo.Insurane_Companies.Company_name, DATEDIFF(year, dbo.Agents.DOB, GETDATE()) AS age, YEAR(dbo.Agents.DateJoined) 
                  AS YearJoined, YEAR(dbo.Agents.Termination_Date2) AS YearTermination, dbo.Agents.REGION, dbo.Agents.DOB AS DOB2, 
                  dbo.Insurane_Companies.Company_code
     FROM         dbo.Agents INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Insurane_Companies ON dbo.Agents.Company_ID = dbo.Insurane_Companies.Company_id
```

Comment: Have you considered indexing your db? Also, since you are fetching from a view, you may consider optimizing the view itself.

Comment: Can you post your SQL code for the view itself?

Comment: Have you tried using a stored procedure?

Comment: Two thousand records is not a big set. I presume the problem might be in the data itself. Try making this query in SSMS and see the execution plan, that might give some leads.

Comment: @jyparask Yes I have indexed the database.

Comment: @aikixd Running from SSMS takes few seconds.. no hustle...James I haven't tried using stored procedures, maybe its worth a shot.

Comment: Try that intercepting the generated query. You can use [Express profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) for it, and see if there's something odd there.

Comment: You could try moving the `Where` and `OrderBy` clauses into the view itself, passing in parameters by using a stored procedure if necessary.

Comment: You could also add [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to your project. Amongst many other things, you can inspect SQL calls to see if you have any unnecessary or time consuming DB hits.

Comment: @tomsullivan1989 moving the orderby did the trick, i can get all my records without timing out.Thanks. But i know that is a temporary solution I think i will go with stored procedure and see

Comment: @Angwenyi I have put it an an answer, mark it as the correct answer if you are happy with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try moving the `Where` and `OrderBy` clauses into the view itself, passing in parameters by using a stored procedure/ user defined function if necessary.

You could also add [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to your project. Amongst many other things, you can inspect SQL calls to see if you have any unnecessary or time consuming DB hits.

Comment: Once more thanks, at least this has taken the heat off for a while.

Answer (score 0):

As James suggested, it would be best to create a stored procedure and call it via LINQ, passing any necessary parameters. This way, the server will handle the processing in the should be much faster since the query would not have to be converted back to SQL to be processed. Other than that you can use SQL's Query Analyzer or Profiler to see what the bottleneck may be.

Comment: Liked as same problem was there and when the query seems static, stored procedure is the best.

Comment: I will give it a shot and give my feedback soon.